# Почему Android-приложение Stack Exchange исчезло из Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353133/837215

1. Почему Android-приложение Stack Exchange исчезло из Play Store?
2. Это что же получается - если я купил приложение через время поменял телефон - могу не увидеть своё купленное приложение только потому что гугл решил что оно устарело?

Я "тут" исключительно любопытства ради. Кто "в теме" расскажите, отредактируйте вопрос, м.б. добавьте ключевых слов ...

Comment: Предистория: решил проверить наличие обновления для приложения, искал сложно и долго, искал через поиск по маркету, искал в списке приложений - нету. 
Думаю, может установл из стороннего источники -  смотрю системную информацию (установлено из googl) ... Приложение просто исчезло - лично я нахожу эту ситуацию дикой (гугл ...)  ....

Comment: По ссылке есть ответ на #1, насчет #2 читайте пользовательское соглашение. Там найдете много для себя интересного :)

Comment: соглашение с кем, как кто? как пользователь или разраб? я не разраб, вот и спрашиваю тут как юзер ...